# Why importing python module is considerably slower on Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a python script that only imports these modules:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import csv
```

When running it on Windows (Anaconda distribution) it takes more than 4 seconds to run it:

```
λ python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)
λ Measure-Command { python ./test.py }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 4
Milliseconds      : 381
Ticks             : 43815980
TotalDays         : 5,07129398148148E-05
TotalHours        : 0,00121711055555556
TotalMinutes      : 0,0730266333333333
TotalSeconds      : 4,381598
TotalMilliseconds : 4381,598
```

However when running the same imports on python3 in "Bash on Ubuntu 16.04 on Windows" I'm getting considerably better performance:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
$ time python3 test.py

real    0m1.657s
user    0m0.563s
sys     0m0.359s
```

What is there such a big difference in module import time?

Comment: That's hardly a benchmark (one run, different python versions, unclear if both are 64-bit, caching?). (I'm not saying there should be no differences)

Comment: How do you time the first one? It's a totally different output. And you're comparing different Python versions. That could have a considerable impact.

Comment: First one runs directly on Windows, second is Bash on Windows. Both are 64-bit and results are consistent across multiple runs.
Output of the time measuring commands are different because commands are different. FIrst one is PowerShell cmdlet Measure-Command while the second is standard linux time command. 
But the output format shouldn't matter - they both measure time.

Comment: FWIW I just ran this on my notebook and got `TotalSeconds      : 0.829841` on Windows and `real 0m1.267s` on my ubuntu virtualbox, so whatever's going on, I don't think it's inherent to the conda setup.

Comment: I tried with python 3.5.3 on Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit (dual-boot) and here running these imports takes about 400ms. This is different OS so I expect differences, but 10x slower import on Windows is still very suspicious.